# Dynamically modify the contents of a React Component before printing PDF

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am using the PDFExport of kendo-react-pdf to generate the pdf of a class component named SummaryComponent. I have the PDFExport tags enclosing the content inside the render function and then I call `this.myRef.current.save();` on click of a link named 'Print Summary'

But there are certain elements like the 'Print Summary' link(which I need to remove from the pdf) , certain  elements from antd which I need to expand when generating the pdf.

This is my function to print the page:

```
generatePDFSummaryPage = () => {
    this.myRef.current.save();
  }
```

Is there a way to do it without rewriting the entire component again without these elements and still leaving the things displayed on UI unchanged?
Is there any way so that I can do this inside generatePDFSummaryPage() ?

Comment: You can use [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas) and [jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)

Comment: Is there a way to modify the Component before generating the PDF ?

Comment: Just call the function to generate PDF when you are done with all the other stuff. For example- when filling a form generate the PDF when the user clicks on submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove links by providing `avoidLinks={true}` to `PDFExport` component